AWS Textract analyze_document function not working with multiple page pdf
import boto3
import os
import pathlib

client = boto3.client('s3')
bucket_name = BUCKET NAME
object_name = FILE NAME
file_name = os.path.join(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve(), PDFNAME)
print(file_name)
response = client.upload_file(file_name, bucket_name, object_name)

client = boto3.client('textract')


queries = {
        "Queries": []
    }

# response = client.start_document_text_detection(
#                    DocumentLocation={'S3Object': {'Bucket': bucket, 'Name': filename} },
#                    ClientRequestToken=random.randint(1,1e10))

response = client.analyze_document(
    Document = {'S3Object': {'Bucket': bucket_name, 'Name': object_name}},
    FeatureTypes=["QUERIES"],
    QueriesConfig = queries
)

for i in range(len(response["Blocks"])):
    if response["Blocks"][i]["BlockType"] == "QUERY_RESULT":
        print(response["Blocks"][i]["Text"])

Got an unsupported document type error when I ran this code, it is only giving me answer with single page pdfs which I upload to s3 and not multiple page pdfs

Analyzing a multi-page document with AWS Textract is an Asynchronous process, and you'll need a polling mechanism to track the status of an analysis process.
Please review the relevant section of the Textract documentation here:

Multipage document processing is an asynchronous operation.

Please refer to this example that uses SNS and SQS for the polling mechanism. A simple alternative could include a while loop with a sleep timer.
Sample code:
import boto3
import json
import sys
import time


class ProcessType:
    DETECTION = 1
    ANALYSIS = 2


class DocumentProcessor:
    jobId = ''
    region_name = ''

    roleArn = ''
    bucket = ''
    document = ''

    sqsQueueUrl = ''
    snsTopicArn = ''
    processType = ''

    def __init__(self, role, bucket, document, region):
        self.roleArn = role
        self.bucket = bucket
        self.document = document
        self.region_name = region

        self.textract = boto3.client('textract', region_name=self.region_name)
        self.sqs = boto3.client('sqs', region_name=self.region_name)
        self.sns = boto3.client('sns', region_name=self.region_name)

    def ProcessDocument(self, type):
        jobFound = False

        self.processType = type
        validType = False

        # Determine which type of processing to perform
        if self.processType == ProcessType.DETECTION:
            response = self.textract.start_document_text_detection(
                DocumentLocation={'S3Object': {'Bucket': self.bucket, 'Name': self.document}},
                NotificationChannel={'RoleArn': self.roleArn, 'SNSTopicArn': self.snsTopicArn})
            print('Processing type: Detection')
            validType = True

        # For document analysis, select which features you want to obtain with the FeatureTypes argument
        if self.processType == ProcessType.ANALYSIS:
            response = self.textract.start_document_analysis(
                DocumentLocation={'S3Object': {'Bucket': self.bucket, 'Name': self.document}},
                FeatureTypes=["TABLES", "FORMS"],
                NotificationChannel={'RoleArn': self.roleArn, 'SNSTopicArn': self.snsTopicArn})
            print('Processing type: Analysis')
            validType = True

        if validType == False:
            print("Invalid processing type. Choose Detection or Analysis.")
            return

        print('Start Job Id: ' + response['JobId'])
        dotLine = 0
        while jobFound == False:
            sqsResponse = self.sqs.receive_message(QueueUrl=self.sqsQueueUrl, MessageAttributeNames=['ALL'],
                                                   MaxNumberOfMessages=10)

            if sqsResponse:

                if 'Messages' not in sqsResponse:
                    if dotLine < 40:
                        print('.', end='')
                        dotLine = dotLine + 1
                    else:
                        print()
                        dotLine = 0
                    sys.stdout.flush()
                    time.sleep(5)
                    continue

                for message in sqsResponse['Messages']:
                    notification = json.loads(message['Body'])
                    textMessage = json.loads(notification['Message'])
                    print(textMessage['JobId'])
                    print(textMessage['Status'])
                    if str(textMessage['JobId']) == response['JobId']:
                        print('Matching Job Found:' + textMessage['JobId'])
                        jobFound = True
                        self.GetResults(textMessage['JobId'])
                        self.sqs.delete_message(QueueUrl=self.sqsQueueUrl,
                                                ReceiptHandle=message['ReceiptHandle'])
                    else:
                        print("Job didn't match:" +
                              str(textMessage['JobId']) + ' : ' + str(response['JobId']))
                    # Delete the unknown message. Consider sending to dead letter queue
                    self.sqs.delete_message(QueueUrl=self.sqsQueueUrl,
                                            ReceiptHandle=message['ReceiptHandle'])

        print('Done!')

    def CreateTopicandQueue(self):

        millis = str(int(round(time.time() * 1000)))

        # Create SNS topic
        snsTopicName = "AmazonTextractTopic" + millis

        topicResponse = self.sns.create_topic(Name=snsTopicName)
        self.snsTopicArn = topicResponse['TopicArn']

        # create SQS queue
        sqsQueueName = "AmazonTextractQueue" + millis
        self.sqs.create_queue(QueueName=sqsQueueName)
        self.sqsQueueUrl = self.sqs.get_queue_url(QueueName=sqsQueueName)['QueueUrl']

        attribs = self.sqs.get_queue_attributes(QueueUrl=self.sqsQueueUrl,
                                                AttributeNames=['QueueArn'])['Attributes']

        sqsQueueArn = attribs['QueueArn']

        # Subscribe SQS queue to SNS topic
        self.sns.subscribe(
            TopicArn=self.snsTopicArn,
            Protocol='sqs',
            Endpoint=sqsQueueArn)

        # Authorize SNS to write SQS queue
        policy = """{{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {{
      "Sid":"MyPolicy",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal" : {{"AWS" : "*"}},
      "Action":"SQS:SendMessage",
      "Resource": "{}",
      "Condition":{{
        "ArnEquals":{{
          "aws:SourceArn": "{}"
        }}
      }}
    }}
  ]
}}""".format(sqsQueueArn, self.snsTopicArn)

        response = self.sqs.set_queue_attributes(
            QueueUrl=self.sqsQueueUrl,
            Attributes={
                'Policy': policy
            })

    def DeleteTopicandQueue(self):
        self.sqs.delete_queue(QueueUrl=self.sqsQueueUrl)
        self.sns.delete_topic(TopicArn=self.snsTopicArn)

    # Display information about a block
    def DisplayBlockInfo(self, block):

        print("Block Id: " + block['Id'])
        print("Type: " + block['BlockType'])
        if 'EntityTypes' in block:
            print('EntityTypes: {}'.format(block['EntityTypes']))

        if 'Text' in block:
            print("Text: " + block['Text'])

        if block['BlockType'] != 'PAGE' and "Confidence" in str(block['BlockType']):
            print("Confidence: " + "{:.2f}".format(block['Confidence']) + "%")

        print('Page: {}'.format(block['Page']))

        if block['BlockType'] == 'CELL':
            print('Cell Information')
            print('\tColumn: {} '.format(block['ColumnIndex']))
            print('\tRow: {}'.format(block['RowIndex']))
            print('\tColumn span: {} '.format(block['ColumnSpan']))
            print('\tRow span: {}'.format(block['RowSpan']))

            if 'Relationships' in block:
                print('\tRelationships: {}'.format(block['Relationships']))

        if ("Geometry") in str(block):
            print('Geometry')
            print('\tBounding Box: {}'.format(block['Geometry']['BoundingBox']))
            print('\tPolygon: {}'.format(block['Geometry']['Polygon']))

        if block['BlockType'] == 'SELECTION_ELEMENT':
            print('    Selection element detected: ', end='')
            if block['SelectionStatus'] == 'SELECTED':
                print('Selected')
            else:
                print('Not selected')

        if block["BlockType"] == "QUERY":
            print("Query info:")
            print(block["Query"])
        
        if block["BlockType"] == "QUERY_RESULT":
            print("Query answer:")
            print(block["Text"])        
                
    def GetResults(self, jobId):
        maxResults = 1000
        paginationToken = None
        finished = False

        while finished == False:

            response = None

            if self.processType == ProcessType.ANALYSIS:
                if paginationToken == None:
                    response = self.textract.get_document_analysis(JobId=jobId,
                                                                   MaxResults=maxResults)
                else:
                    response = self.textract.get_document_analysis(JobId=jobId,
                                                                   MaxResults=maxResults,
                                                                   NextToken=paginationToken)

            if self.processType == ProcessType.DETECTION:
                if paginationToken == None:
                    response = self.textract.get_document_text_detection(JobId=jobId,
                                                                         MaxResults=maxResults)
                else:
                    response = self.textract.get_document_text_detection(JobId=jobId,
                                                                         MaxResults=maxResults,
                                                                         NextToken=paginationToken)

            blocks = response['Blocks']
            print('Detected Document Text')
            print('Pages: {}'.format(response['DocumentMetadata']['Pages']))

            # Display block information
            for block in blocks:
                self.DisplayBlockInfo(block)
                print()
                print()

            if 'NextToken' in response:
                paginationToken = response['NextToken']
            else:
                finished = True

    def GetResultsDocumentAnalysis(self, jobId):
        maxResults = 1000
        paginationToken = None
        finished = False

        while finished == False:

            response = None
            if paginationToken == None:
                response = self.textract.get_document_analysis(JobId=jobId,
                                                               MaxResults=maxResults)
            else:
                response = self.textract.get_document_analysis(JobId=jobId,
                                                               MaxResults=maxResults,
                                                               NextToken=paginationToken)

                # Get the text blocks
            blocks = response['Blocks']
            print('Analyzed Document Text')
            print('Pages: {}'.format(response['DocumentMetadata']['Pages']))
            # Display block information
            for block in blocks:
                self.DisplayBlockInfo(block)
                print()
                print()

                if 'NextToken' in response:
                    paginationToken = response['NextToken']
                else:
                    finished = True


def main():
    roleArn = ''
    bucket = ''
    document = ''
    region_name = ''

    analyzer = DocumentProcessor(roleArn, bucket, document, region_name)
    analyzer.CreateTopicandQueue()
    analyzer.ProcessDocument(ProcessType.ANALYSIS)
    analyzer.DeleteTopicandQueue()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Goodluck!
